# Can two wait operations executed by two separate threads on different semaphores be interleaved during execution?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, semaphore

I'm motivated with this citation from "Concepts in Programming Languages" by John C. Mitchell:

> "*Atomicity prevents individual statements of one wait procedure from being
>   interleaved with individual statements of another wait **on the same semaphore**.*"

Wait and signal operations need to be atomic which is often enforced by some "lower" level mechanism of acquiring lock - disabling interrupts, disabling preemption, test and set ... But, conceptually, how these locks can be in some way "private" for each semaphore instance?

In other words, is it allowed for example that one thread acquires lock at the beginning and later  be preempted in the middle of executing wait operation on one semaphore, and after that another thread acquires lock at the beginning of wait operation on some other semaphore and enters in the body of its wait operation, so  that two thread are in the wait operations on different semaphores at the same time? Or, shortly, whether the wait operations on **two different semaphores** mutually exclusive?

My point is, if thread acquires lock in wait operation **on one semaphore** s1, is it allowed for another thread to acquire lock at the same time in wait operation **on another semaphore** s2? I'm emphasizing that these are two different semaphore instances, not the same one.

For example:

```
class Semaphore {
...
    public:
        void wait();
...
}

 void Semaphore::wait(){
      lock();
      //POINT OF CONTINUATION FOR THREAD 2!//
      if(--val<0){
          //POINT OF PREEMPTION FOR THREAD 1!//
          block();
      }
      unlock();
 }

 Semaphore s1;
 Semaphore s2:
 ...
```

So...

Is it allowed at some point of execution that one thread be preempted while executing wait operation on semaphore s1 at //POINT OF PREEMPTION FOR THREAD 1!// , and control transfers to another thread which executes wait operation of semaphore s2 at //POINT OF CONTINUATION FOR THREAD 2!//...

...or...

Is it allowed for instructions of wait operation from one semaphore to be interleaved with instruction of wait operation from another semaphore?

..or...

Is it allowed for more than one threads to be in wait operations on **different** semaphores at the same time?

Sorry for my wordiness but I really struggle to clarify my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking. Signals and semaphores are just different tools in your concurrency toolbox. (There are others.) Different tools are better suited for different things.

Comment: Peterson's Algorithm is more of an academic exercise. It makes assumptions that may not be necessarily guaranteed when you try to implement it. It is better to rely on hardware instructions designed for enforcing mutual exclusion.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I tried to clarify my point so I edited question. My question is more about implementation of semaphores and is there any requirement by definition of wait/signal operation that they must be physically indivisible?

Comment: Don't forget that a signal handler can itself be interrupted if another signal is received.

Comment: Ok, but if we disable all maskable interrupts then we prevent any asynchronous preemption which is the point of my question (for example initiated by timer) and transfer of control can be enforced only by will of process that currently use processor (for example by executing instruction for software interrupt).

Comment: Just because _you_ can't be interrupted by a signal doesn't mean that someone else is prevented from accessing a critical section or protected data. The point of mutual exclusion is to ensure that _no one else_ has access to something. Signals are inappropriate for enforcing this.

Comment: "The point of mutual exclusion is to ensure that no one else has access to something"... OK, so wait operations of two semaphore instances s1 and s2 from my example does not share data... Does that two executions of wait operations on s1 by one process and s2 by another process must be mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed. One of the reasons you would use two different locks, rather than using the same lock for everything, is to avoid unnecessary dependencies like this.

> Is it allowed for instructions of wait operation from one semaphore to be interleaved with instruction of wait operation from another semaphore?

Absolutely.

> Is it allowed for more than one threads to be in wait operations on different semaphores at the same time?

Absolutely.

Prohibiting any of these things would hurt performance significantly for no benefit. Contention is the enemy of multi-threaded performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for Your answer. But then how we would implement different locks per semahore on uniprocessor system without disabling interrupts or preemption? Should we then use some busy-waiting alghoritms instead?

Comment: I don't follow your question. If you chose to use different locks, it means you don't want anything special, so there's nothing special to do -- we don't care if there's pre-emption or not. If you use the same lock, then the lock protects things, that's its job.

Comment: I mean if acquiring a lock needs to be atomic, how can we enforce it? Or, more concrete, how should I implement lock(); and unlock(); operations in the example in my question, in order to provide effect that more separate threads can be in wait operations on different semaphores at the same time?

Comment: It depends on the hardware. Typically, it's done by pinning the cache line containing the locked/unlocked flag into the cache during an atomic instruction during which the CPU prevents interruption. With no hardware help, you might have to disable interrupts.

Comment: "With no hardware help, you might have to disable interrupts". If I understand well, for implementations of lock() and unlock() I can not use some of the busy-waiting algorithm's entry and exit protocols (for example Decker's algorithm) which do not require special hardware instructions and relies on atomicity of conventional read/write instructions ?

Comment: If you have no choice, you can. But no modern system requires such awful things. Those kinds of algorithms are basically used to prove that no special hardware support is *required*, but they perform terribly and are really more theoretical curiosities than things you should actually use. You should use whatever is best on your hardware, and for modern CPUs, they typically provide instructions that are uninterruptible and lock the cache line.

Comment: David, thanks a lot for your patience and all clarifications. Ok, I didn't mentioned that my question is a little bit theoretical, but you clarified all to me. Thank you very much, again.